# ¿Cómo puedo ver el perfil de un usuario registrado en Firebase usando un Search Bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo esta aplicación donde los usuarios de la misma pueden crear una cuenta y subir información variada a su cuenta. Estos usuarios pueden ver su información registrada iniciando sesión. Sin embargo, yo necesito que alguien que NO tenga una cuenta registrada pueda leer (mas no escribir) dicha información de cada uno de los usuarios, pero para esto, debo de hacerlo mediante un Search Bar y, cuando de clic a alguno de los usuarios que encontró el Search Bar, me muestre el perfil de ese usuario en particular, ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Añado algunas imágenes para entender mejor qué necesito.
Este es mi Search Bar. Aquí necesito buscar y encontrar, sin tener una cuenta, a algún usuario que esté previamente registrado: [image: Imagen de mi Search Bar]

Una vez que yo le de clic a cualquiera de los usuarios que aparecen al hacer la búsqueda, tendría que mostrarme una pantalla similar a esta: [image: Imagen del perfil del usuario AL INICIAR SESIÓN]

(Esta segunda imagen es lo que un usuario ve al iniciar sesión, yo necesito mostrar esta misma información sin iniciar ningún tipo de sesión, solo con buscarlo).

Este es mi código:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:phonectedflutter2/Crearcuenta.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:phonectedflutter2/Comprobacionedad.dart';
import 'package:phonectedflutter2/Crearcuenta.dart';
import 'package:phonectedflutter2/Ingresarcliente.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:phonectedflutter2/PinturasPan.dart';
import 'package:phonectedflutter2/Verlodatos.dart';
import 'Infoestablecimientocliente.dart';
import 'package:phonectedflutter2/Verdatos.dart';
import 'package:phonectedflutter2/HospitalesPan.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';

import 'Iniciarsesion.dart';

class NoRestriccion extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  NoresApp createState () => NoresApp();
}

class NoresApp extends State<NoRestriccion>{
  List searchResult = [];

  void searchFromFirebase(String query) async{
    final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('Nombre', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query).get();
    setState(() {
      searchResult = result.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'PhoNected',
      home: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFffff8d),
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 110,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            color: Colors.black,
            iconSize: 35,
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> Comprobacionedad()) ),
          ),
          title: Column(
            children: [
              Text('PhoNected',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 50)),
            ],
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30), bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Color(0xFFffff00),Colors.orangeAccent],
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topCenter
              ),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 170,right: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),

                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Busque un establecimiento aquí...',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (query) {
                    searchFromFirebase(query);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                width: 600,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    itemCount: searchResult.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(searchResult[index]['Nombre']),
                        subtitle: Text(searchResult[index]['Tipo']),
                        focusColor: Colors.yellow,
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> Verlodatos()) );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 30,right: 20),
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.amberAccent, width: 4),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 150,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> HospitalesPan()) );
                      },
                      child: Ink.image(
                        image: AssetImage('image/Hospitales.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 30,right: 20),
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.amberAccent, width: 4),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 150,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> PinturasPan()) );
                      },
                      child: Ink.image(
                        image: AssetImage('image/Pinturas4.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no entiendo bien tu pregunta pero al hacer la query a la collection user ¿te da algun error?

Comment: Buenas. Ok, para hacerme entender mejor, te explico con un ejemplo. Supón que entras a Twitter y no tienes una cuenta de Twitter y quieres ver el perfil de Messi (por poner un nombre). Tecleas Messi en el buscador de Twitter y te salen varias opciones, le das clic a la opción de Messi y te debe de mandar al perfil de Messi, eso es lo que yo necesito, buscar a algún usuario en mi Search Bar, darle clic y que me muestre el perfil de dicho usuario. La búsqueda de usuarios me lo hace bien, el problema es a la hora de querer ver su perfil, me manda una pantalla roja.

Comment: En la pantalla roja que te sale? muy probablemente sea porque uno de los atributos es nulo

Comment: Null check operator used on a null value See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors
Sabía que me daría ese problema porque estoy usando exactamente el mismo código que uso para cuando un usuario iniciar sesión en su cuenta, pero no sé cómo llamar esa información sin iniciar sesión.

Comment: Claro, puedes poner el código de la página a la que quieres navegar que te bota el error? Para que no te bote error, tienes que hacer una consulta con el id del usuario que estás seleccionando en el LisTile, yo normalmente creo una función para llamar a la api y obtener los datos, mientras eso pasa muestro un loading en pantalla

Comment: No supe cómo mandar el código, así que lo subí a GitHub, aquí te dejo el link https://github.com/Pripri115/Pantalla-que-muestra-error/blob/main/pantalla    En el código que puse aquí en esta publicación solo llamo el nombre y el tipo del usuario, pero no sabría cómo hacer la función que mencionas.

Comment: El código debe ir _en la pregunta misma_, no como enlace externo. No olvides que debe ser un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_), no tooodo tu proyecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerte un ejemplo rápido y sencillo, tu en Firebase tienes una collection de `users`, obviamente cada usuario debe tener su identificador.

De igual forma tienes una funcion `searchFromFirebase` y este te arroja como resultado la lista de usuarios con este nombre, pero no únicamente te va a arrojar el nombre y el tipo, te va a arrojar todos los datos de ese usuario, pero tu solo estás mostrando el nombre y el tipo, hasta ahí todo está bien, ahora tenemos que cambiar de página, específicamente donde vas a mostrar los datos de este usuario y le vamos a asignar un parámetro obligatorio que va a ser el id del usuario:

```
    class Verlodatos extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? idUser;
  
  const Verlodatos({Key? key, required this.idUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Verlodatos> createState() => _VerlodatosState();
}

class _VerlodatosState extends State<Verlodatos> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Una vez que hagas esto, te va a salir un error en la página donde buscas el usuario por nombre, tendrás que asignarle el valor al parámetro:

```
ListTile(
  title: Text(searchResult[index]['Nombre']),
  subtitle: Text(searchResult[index]['Tipo']),
  focusColor: Colors.yellow,
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Verlodatos(idUser: searchResult[index]["Id"])));//no se si así esté declarado en el mapa, tu validas eso.
  },
);
```

Ahora tendríamos que regresar a la página de `Verlodatos` y crear una función similar a la `searchFromFirebase`, solo que buscarás por el id que estás pasando como parámetro:

```
class _VerlodatosState extends State<Verlodatos> {
  List searchResult = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.idUser != null) {
      searchUserID();
    }
  }

  void searchUserID() async {
    final user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('ID', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: widget.idUser)
        .get();

    if (user != null) {
      //Un consejo.. aquí sería bueno que en vez de declarar una lista o un mapa del objeto, mejor crees un modelo, donde vayas asignando los datos, para que sea más sencillo para ti.
      setState(() {
        searchResult = user.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
        //Aquí asignarías en los campos los valores que te devuelve USER siempre y cuando no sea null
        //Ejemplo de como quedaría:
        controllerNombre.text = searchResult[0]['Nombre'];
        controllerTipo.text = searchResult[0]['Tipo'];
        //...
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //...
  }
```

En el `initState` validamos que si el `idUser` es diferente de `null` se ejecute la función, esto lo hacemos para que en el login podamos enviar el parámetro `idUser` nulo y el usuario pueda registrarse. Espero y mi respuesta te haya servido.

Por último, sería bueno que cuando estés consultando en la base los datos del usuario muestres un `CircularProgressIndicator` en pantalla, para que el usuario sepa que se está ejecutando una acción.

Comment: Apliqué lo que pusiste y funcionó correctamente, muchísimas gracias.